# Google Places JavaScript Autocomplete: can I remove the country from the place name?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I have the following jQuery code which works well with getting the city list for the selected country.

```
var city;   var place;

$('#city').on('focus',function(){
    input = this, options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: $('#country option:selected').val()
            }
    };
    city = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(city, 'place_changed', function() {
        place = city.getPlace();
        $(input).val(place.address_components[0].long_name);
    })
})
```

Basically, once the person selects the place, it replaces the value in the input box with the "city" value without the country.

It looks a little stupid having `City, Country` in the dropdown menu when the user has already selected a country, so does anybody know if it is possible to display JUST the city name if you have defined a `componentRestrictions` value restricting the results to a country?

I find my current method of setting it once the selection has been made to be a bit... rubbish really...

Comment: I've read through your question several times and I don't feel like I completely understand what you are describing. I think maybe if you included some of the markup, it would give the question some context and help everyone understand. Or maybe a link to your page or an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Generally speaking, can you edit what's in the dropdown? I mean, if the country name is known, `replace` it out of the dropdown displayed entry.

Comment: The dropdown is generated by Google. also a fiddle of the code would not work and a link to my page would be no help what-so-ever as once the problem is fixed it would not appear on the page, rendering the question useless once it has been answered for any other people wanting to do something like this.

Comment: @AndrewWillis It's very common for folks on here to share links or set up a jsFiddle to look at things more deeply and share ideas. It's customary after that process, to add follow-up comments or question/answer edits to be sure that what was learned from that process is saved for the benefit of everyone. If you don't want to share a link or set up a jsFiddle, it's cool, but it makes it hard for anyone to understand the details of what you want to achieve or what may be the root of your problem. If you give it a try, I guarantee you will see more activity on this question. Just trying to help-

Comment: I know, I have set up fiddles for other questions BUT with Google Places, the API only works on my domain and, as such, would require me to reconfigure the application. It would also use up my daily limit of queries while people try out their code!

Comment: Ahhh, right, now that makes more sense. But it's not the same as saying the approach is "no help what-so-ever" or that it will render "the question useless." Ease the tude dude; people are just **trying to help you.** I've gone through your question again and I get it now; I thought you were trying to do something deeper. You just want to control the content of the `Autocomplete` that comes back. Adding an answer for the good of the community.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When invoking Google API, specify attribute "region":

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&key=your_key&language=fr&region=FR"></script>
```

Then, when you create an [`Autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions) object, specify the country in the `componentRestriction` attribute, so that it reflects the region you specified:

```
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        $("#my-input-field").get(0),
        {
            componentRestrictions: {country: "fr"},
            types: ["(regions)"]
        }
    );
```

Comment: Is this a new feature to the Google Maps API? I posted this question almost two years ago!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for US. But others seems to be fine.

Comment: Works with `region=US` for me!

Comment: Works in Ireland with &region=IE appended to the Google maps script URL.

Answer (score 7):

Also you can help yourself by css - hiding last span (=state) in autocomplete item.

```
.pac-item > span:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Since that hides the country and state, this is not a solution in the many cases where numerous states have a city with the same name. E.g., in the US four states have a city called Independence.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: the response content in the `Autocomplete` is controlled by Google (you mention this in one of your comments) and the `Autocomplete`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) doesn't provide a way to customize the response text that is displayed, other than **changing the placeholder text**[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#changing_the_placeholder_text). The solution you are using is about the best option you have (and is a little reactive, but I don't know if its really "rubbish").

Other than that, if you are less than satisfied with that approach, you could always just create your own input area and take complete control of the request-response back and forth yourself. You can use the Places Library[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) directly and take complete control of everything that is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I wait 100 milleseconds, and then replace the text box with the content I want.

Except in my case I want a blank box, but insert a single space.