# google autocomplete remove state

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have a working autocomplete with the google maps API.

With the options I managed to limit the country and results to cities:

```
var options = {                                                                                                   
    types:['(cities)'],                                                                                   
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'my'}                                                                
};
```

But in the results it shows the cities followed by the state.

[image: googleautcomplete]

Is there a way to remove the state from the result and only show the cityname? I am unable to find that option so far.

Comment: This [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626727/google-places-javascript-autocomplete-can-i-remove-the-country-from-the-place-n) might be helpful. It suggested to specify attribute "city" when invoking Google API. Then, when you create an [`Autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions) object, specify the country in the <code>componentRestriction</code> attribute, so that it reflects the city you specified.

Comment: That's what I do with the options you see in my post, I restrict the results to cities and restrict the country to Malaysia. In the mentioned thread the trick with the CSS works to hide the states, but once you select the state it shows back in the selected result.