# How to stop the county name in dropdown list of google auto places

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am new to google auto complete api. how can I remove the county in dropdown of auto complete places.

In drop down list displays with country name, but I want to display without country name.

For ex: when I search for Bridgewater.

Search result list like [Bridgewater,NJ,United states]

But I need to display like [Bridgewater,NJ]

I have tried as like below.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=places"></script>
  <script>
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], {
        componentRestrictions: {country: "us"},
        types: ["(regions)"]
        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place.address_components);
        });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="address" style="width: 500px;"></input> 
</body>
</html>
```

Any one can help me
Thanks in Advance......

Comment: this post might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626727/google-places-javascript-autocomplete-can-i-remove-the-country-from-the-place-n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Places JavaScript Autocomplete: can I remove the country from the place name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626727/google-places-javascript-autocomplete-can-i-remove-the-country-from-the-place-n)